# In JSfiddle how come it doesn't like @keyframes in my css?

Tags: css, jsfiddle

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PinG1/vyqmpL3f/19/

```
@keyframes example {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 100;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
```

As you can see JS fiddle does not like @keyframes and keeps returning an error. I don't know why and am trying to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `@`in the *jsfiddle* code. Also, there is no closing curly bracket (`}`).

It should be like this:

```
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 100;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you did not close your keyframes you left it open :

```
keyframes example {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 100;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
```

Second, you did not add @. Fixed version:

```
@keyframes example {
  0% { opacity: 0;} 
  50% { opacity: 100; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

You also never specified where you were gonna use the keyframes.